# Google Cast - Sample Android app not showing Cast icon if I change App ID

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I'm working with the [CastHelloText-android project from Googlecast Github](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android)  because I want to understand how the messages between the Sender and the (Chrome)cast Receiver works.

I registered my device (Console says *Ready for Testing*).
I checked out mentioned project from Github. I've tested it on my Android phone with my Chromecast. Everything worked ok. I can connect and speak to the phone and when I finish the TV screen is updated with what I said. Nice.

I saw that this project uses the App ID *79####BF*. I also saw that there's one folder that contains the [receiver.html Custom Receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/blob/master/receiver/receiver.html). I opened it and it seems taht there's no reference to that App ID so I left as is and then I uploaded that HTML file to my [Google Drive](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bxkveal4MLbkY1FUNTBTVlg1a0U).

Then, I went to [Cast Developers Console](https://cast.google.com/publish) and I created a new Application with Custom Receiver and name Cast Hello Text. For the Receiver I provided exactly that URL from Google Drive. They gave me an App ID *8A####7E* which I put into the App ID string, replacing the mentioned above.

*What would you expect from this?* Personally I was expecting that everything worked exactly equals as with the original App ID but with the only difference that is hosted in another site. But no! With this App ID I can't see the Cast icon. But if I go back again to original ID then it appears.

I can't find an answer. I've been dealing with this for long hours so I decided ask here.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I didn't touch anything from the code.

I'll put code pieces if necessary, but I gave the links to entire Github project and I consider that is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the way you have exposed your receiver in your google drive is incorrect; when you correctly expose the receiver using goole drive, it should look like: `https://www.googledrive.com/host/[doc-id]`. Here is a set of [instructions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) to do that. Secondly, to have an unpublished app visible on your cast device, you need to follow the steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration), specially look under the section Devices (step 3 is a common issue, take a photo to ensure you are entering the right serial number, also make sure you have done step 6 as well).

Update: Google Drive is no longer a viable hosting place for receivers.

Comment: I updated links of Google Drive in the Dev Console and in the question, still same issue (File is called receiver.html). Second paragraph of my question says I did all you mention secondly. Is whitelistes. Few hours ago with another test I could enter the Debug Console on the IP of Chromecast and port 9222. Now I can't enter because the app is never open on the TV.

Comment: Man! Thanks! Now it works! I turned off the TV and Chromecast and took a nap. But I turned both on now and it works! Maybe the link was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer post. I verified it was all good. A restart to the google-cast device helped me fix the issue. Thanks @joaquin :P

Comment: Is step 7 also necessary? I.e. submitting the package name of the sender app.